# Google Script E-mail confirmation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My goal is to have a form that fills out a spreadsheet. Part of the form will have an e-mail address and another with is task complete. I want it to be if I switch the spreadsheet from no to yes under task complete to e-mail the user with a confirmation saying so. I don't know if it is possible but any help would be appreciated.

Edit :

This code is what I have down now to do the task. I like the way it is setup up but there are 2 major issues that I want to try and solve. First being when the script runs lets say I skip over a row the script will fail and not keep trying more entries down the rows. Second issue is I am not sure how to control who is sending the script e-mail past where it asks you to okay and run the script the first time.

```
// This constant is written in column O for rows for which an email
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 1000;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells M2:N1000
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 1000)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[12];  // First column
    var message = row[13];       // Second column
    var emailSent = row[14];     // Third column
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = "Help Desk Completion Response";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 15).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The e-mail will always be sent as the user that runs the script. You can have the script run as the result of an installable trigger which you can set on any Google account with access to the script and the script will then send the e-mail as that Google account. For example, have the script run once a day using a time-based trigger and check the values for EMAIL_SENT and TASK_COMPLETE, if the task is complete but the e-mail is not sent, then have the script send an e-mail. This should also solve the empty row problem because when TASK_COMPLETE is empty rather than "Yes" it will not try to send an e-mail.

If you want to make the script send an e-mail immediately you will need an edit-based trigger. In this case you may not even need to load the entire spreadsheet but a simple e.range.offset() may suffice.

Something like:

```
//This constant is written in column O for rows for which an email
//has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function sendEmails(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var columnNumber = e.range.getColumn(); //check if the changed value is TASK_COMPLETE
  if(columnNumber = 5 && e.value = "Yes") {
    var row = e.range.offset(0, -5, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var emailAddress = row[12];  // First column
    var message = row[13];       // Second column
    var emailSent = row[14];     // Third column
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = "Help Desk Completion Response";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      e.range.offset(0,9).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Of course the exact offsets depend on where exactly in your spreadsheet things are located.